# Mobile apps being completely sunsetted

Tags: discussion

I’m guessing that I may be the only EL&U regular this impacts, but just bringing it to your attention for those who don’t follow the big Meta:

[StackExchange native mobile apps being completely sunsetted](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/383026/273503)

The apps have been deprecated for a long while, and haven’t been available in the respective app stores for years, but for those of us who had them installed already they worked more-or-less fine despite that.

But over the next few weeks all server-side infrastructure which supports them is being shut down, and they will stop working partially, and then completely.

I’m kinda sad about it, the iOS app is my main (more honestly: only) interface to EL&U and SE more broadly. It was nice to have a dedicated app for it, like for twitter or reddit or what-have-you.

I plan to create an icon on my phone that links to the mobile site, and we’ll see if that is a workable alternative. If not, you probably won’t hear much from me going forward.

Comment: I uninstalled the mobile app a fair bit,  the full site mode works just fine.

Comment: I never knew there was an ELU mobile app, but I wouldn't've used it if I had. Language is hard enough without mixing it with ephemeral smushware.

Comment: @JohnLawler I don’t know how to break this to you, John, but …. whatever thingy you typed that comment into is ephemeral smushware.

Comment: I have edited your post, restoring the original "decommissioned". There are three reasons for this. 1. It is used in the link you cite. 2. It is English, rather than the sort of jargon that some on this list find abhorrent. 3. It uses a familiar word that will communicate the idea to a larger group of people. This is a basic principle of communication and in the IT world is part of user interface design.

Comment: @JohnLawler There wasn't a ELU mobile app, it was a *Stack Exchange* app. It was natural for our StackOverflow parent to produce an app when the iPhone appeared. There was a reason too: it provided a more convenient mobile interface that was easier to use than on the web browser app at the time. Subsequently: 1. The range of makes and sizes of mobile devices expanded making apps more expensive to support. 2. It became easier to produce web pages that adapted to mobile devices as this became a necessity and the technology was developed. (And comments that make use of meaningless words...)

Comment: I still find the mobile app more pleasant to use on the phone than the site.  But oh well, I wasn't consulted.

Comment: @DanBron Wondering if you have found any success with the mobile website instead of the sunsetted app.

Comment: @NVZ Not much. Because it's in the mobile browser along with my other tabs, it tends to be messier, and re-hitting the homescreen icon ends up opening multiple ELU tabs over time.  Also, the loss of real-estate to the browser chrome around it means everything is more compressed, and overall the experience feels "flatter", the app felt more lively.

Answer (score 3):

I had the same heartache, but a long while ago, and I tried the mobile site, which is now my daily driver even for basic moderation tasks. It's getting good, actually.

Comment: What do you mean "The mobile site"? Do you mean SE on mobile devices? That's the same site with the style sheets determining how the page appears.

Comment: @David I don't know how to put it since I'm not from IT background. But the default what appears on mobile browser is what I meant by mobile site. This is not the same when I tick mark 'desktop site' on chrome for Android's settings.

Comment: OK. In the early days of mobile devices people wrote two separate sets of web pages, one for desktop and one for mobile. These were mobile sites. Web pages have (at least) two sorts of information: the HTML that determines the content and how it is structured; and the CSS (cascading style sheets) which determines how this is displayed. Now one can write a style sheet so that the styles adapt to different width viewing areas by changing appearance and even make certain things invisible — for the same HTML page, i.e. a single site. The 'desktop' option is if you don't want this adaptation.

Comment: @David thanks for clarifying. So I guess it's the mobile adaptation of the website itself. It's quite alright to use.

Comment: Sure. However it's other aspects of using a mobile device that cause me difficulty. I tend not to read posts properly and make deficient responses. Also, if I am writing a considered answer I always like to do it on a word processor first so I can edit it properly and do spelling and grammar checks. I find that more difficult on mobile devices. Nevertheless, I use my iPhone a lot on SE.

Comment: @David I share the same preferences for writing in detail. Mobile is... for mobile writing.